# When I use tcpdf with html and base64 image I only see an white square instead of my image

Tags: php, html, base64, tcpdf

I'm trying to create a pdf using tcpdf library with php. I have a template html file which is filled with data from database and then printed as pdf. There is also an image that should be included in the file. The image is stored on server so I can't use  for loading image. I tried using base64 inside my html:

```
$path = $cardInfo['picsrc'];
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = '<div><span>Hi</span><img src="data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data) . "\"/><span>Bye</span></div>";
$pdf->writeHTML($base64);
```

The base64 is correct and I can see the image when I copy it into an html file. But I cant see my image in the pdf. I only see an empty white square like the image below:
[image: Output pdf image]

I put the full code here:

```
$pdf = new MYTCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->SetPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$l = Array();
$l['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$l['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$l['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$l['w_page'] = 'page';
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 14, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage('L', 'A4');
$path = $cardInfo['picsrc'];
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$base64 = '<div><span>Hi</span><img src="data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data) . "\"/><span>Bye</span></div>";
$pdf->writeHTML($base64);
```

I use tcpdf version 6.3.2

Comment: I used $pdf->Image() instead of using <img> tag. It is harder to use because I should change x, y, w, h every time that I change my html. But I didn't find any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try echo the encoded image in `img src`:

```
<?php
 $encode_img ='"data:image/'. $type.';base64,'.base64_encode($data).'"';
?>
<img src=<?php echo $encode_img; ?>>
```